# clarify the non-overlapped part regarding OS

Tags: architecture, operating-system, cpu-architecture, processor

[image]

In this, a program is being initiated by OS- first the program is being transferred from disk to memory, then executed and then part of program is concerned with reading data file from disk to memory, performing some computation on data & printing the result. This is the non-overlapping version since the OS is idle when either the printer or the disk is running the job - the overlapping version is clear to me that while disk is being read or printer is busy the OS can handle other programs (concurrent execution).

---

Now the part at which I am stuck is what will be the ratio of the best overlapped time to the non-overlapped time for a long sequence of programs.
The intervals be 1 unit for OS, 3 for disk operation, 3 for printing and 2 for program. My approach is (which is result of unclear understanding perhaps) in the best overlapping the condition the OS is never idle. What should be the right approach?

Comment: I think you are somewhat confused.  It's normally considered optimal if the OS kernel is not entered at all and user threads/ processes are using all the available CPU execution.  Obviously, that is unrealistic overall since that would mean that the threads cound not perform any I/O and so would be essentially useless:)

Comment: @MartinJames I got this question from a book (Carl hemacher - computer organization & embedded system 5th ed)! I can't imagine OS dealing with several other processes (of same requirement/nature) when one of the processes is using disk or printer or is busy with program!

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in most systems:

> In this, a program is being initiated by OS- first the program is being transferred from disk to memory,

The executable image tells the program loader how to set up the virtual address space. The program gets transferred from disk to memory when the there are page faults. Programs fault like mad when they first start up.